# English translation of dhyana shloka (opening prayer) of Mahabharata?

Tags: mahabharata, translation-request

From [here](http://gretil.sub.uni-goettingen.de/gretil/1_sanskr/2_epic/mbh/mbh_01_u.htm), following is what looks like the dhyana shloka (opening prayer) for the Mahabharata. I'm looking for an English translation of the same.

> 01,000.000*0001_01       jayati parāśarasūnuḥ satyavatīhṛdayanandano vyāsaḥ
>   01,000.000*0001_02       yasyāsyakamalakośe vāṅmayam amṛtaṃ pibati lokaḥ
>   01,000.000*0002_01       dharmadṛḍhabaddhamūlo vedaskandhaḥ purāṇaśākhāḍhyaḥ
>   01,000.000*0002_02       kratukusumo mokṣaphalo jayati kalpadrumo viṣṇuḥ
>   01,000.000*0003_01       pitāmahādyaṃ pravadanti ṣaṣṭhaṃ; maharṣim akṣayyavibhūtiyuktam
>   01,000.000*0003_02       nārāyaṇasyāṃśajam ekaputraṃ; dvaipāyanaṃ vedanidhiṃ namāmi
>   01,000.000*0004_01       pārāśaryavacassarojam amalaṃ gītārthagandhotkaṭaṃ
>   01,000.000*0004_02       nānākhyānakakesaraṃ harikathāsaṃbodhanābodhitam
>   01,000.000*0004_03       loke sajjanaṣaṭpadair aharahaḥ pepīyamānaṃ mudā
>   01,000.000*0004_04       bhūyād bhāratapaṅkajaṃ kalimalapradhvaṃsi naḥ śreyase
>   01,000.000*0005_01       yaḥ śvetatvam upāgataḥ kṛtayuge tretāyuge raktatāṃ
>   01,000.000*0005_02       yugme yaḥ kapilaḥ kalau ca bhagavān kṛṣṇatvam āyāga *
>   01,000.000*0005_03       . . . . . . . danti munayo yo yogibhir gīyate
>   01,000.000*0005_04       sa brahmā yadi vā haro yadi śivo yaḥ ko 'pi tasmai namaḥ
>   01,000.000*0006_01       vāgīśādyāḥ sumanasaḥ sarvārthānām u . . .
>   01,000.000*0006_02       . . tvā kṛtakṛtyāḥ syus taṃ namāmi gajānanam
>   01,000.000*0007_01       vyāsaṃ vasiṣṭhanaptāraṃ śakteḥ pautram akalmaṣam
>   01,000.000*0007_02       parāśarātmajaṃ vande śukatātaṃ taponidhim
>   01,000.000*0008_01       acaturvadano brahmā dvibāhur a . . . .
>   01,000.000*0008_02       abhālalocanaḥ śambhur bhagavān bādarāyaṇaḥ
>   01,000.000*0009_01       śuklāmbaradharaṃ devaṃ śaśivarṇaṃ caturbhujam
>   01,000.000*0009_02       prasannavadanaṃ dhyāyet sarvavighnopaśāntaye
>   01,000.000*0010_01       jñānānandamayaṃ devaṃ nirmalaṃ sphaṭikākṛtim
>   01,000.000*0010_02       ādhāraṃ sarvavidyānāṃ hayagrīvam upāsmahe
>   01,000.000*0011_01       vyāsāya viṣṇurūpāya vyāsarūpāya viṣṇave
>   01,000.000*0011_02       namo vai brahmanidhaye vāsiṣṭhāya namo namaḥ
>   01,000.000*0012_01       namo dharmāya mahate namaḥ kṛṣṇāya vedhase
>   01,000.000*0012_02       brāhmaṇebhyo namaskṛtvā dharmān vakṣyāmi śāśvatān
>   01,000.000*0013_01       abhraśyāmaḥ piṅgajaṭābaddhakalāpaḥ
>   01,000.000*0013_02       prāṃśur daṇḍī kṛṣṇamṛgatvakparidhānaḥ
>   01,000.000*0013_03       sākṣāl lokān pāvayamānaḥ kavimukhyaḥ
>   01,000.000*0013_04       pārāśaryaḥ parvasu rūpaṃ vivṛṇotu
>   01,000.000*0014_01       aśubhāni nirācaṣṭe tanoti śubhasaṃtatim
>   01,000.000*0014_02       smṛtamātreṇa yaḥ puṃsāṃ brahma tan maṅgalaṃ viduḥ
>   01,000.000*0015_01       dharmo vivardhati yudhiṣṭhirakīrtanena
>   01,000.000*0015_02       pāpaṃ praṇaśyati vṛkodarakīrtanena
>   01,000.000*0015_03       śatrur vinaśyati dhanaṃjayakīrtanena
>   01,000.000*0015_04       mādrīsutau kathayatāṃ na bhavanti rogāḥ
>   01,000.000*0016_01       sarasvatīpadaṃ vande śriyaḥ patim umāpatim
>   01,000.000*0016_02       tviṣāṃ patiṃ gaṇapatiṃ bṛhaspatimukhān ṛṣīn
>   01,000.000*0017_01       nārāyaṇaṃ suraguruṃ jagadekanāthaṃ
>   01,000.000*0017_02       bhaktapriyaṃ sakalalokanamaskṛtaṃ ca
>   01,000.000*0017_03       traiguṇyavarjitam ajaṃ vibhum ādyam īśaṃ
>   01,000.000*0017_04       vande bhavaghnam asurāsurasiddhavandyam

Comment: Hmm, I've never heard of this preamble before.  Some of these verses are used in the preamble that'a traditionally used before reciting the Vishnu Sahasranamam.  In any case, Dhyana Shlokas isn't the right term for these verses (except perhaps for verse 9).  A Dhyana Shloka is a verse that describes what the Devata (deity) of a prayer looks like, so that you can meditate upon his appearance.  You can call these verse invocatory verses, but not Dhyana Shlokas.

Comment: pg. no. 58 of http://www.dvaipayana.net/books/ppssastri-mbh/ppssastri-adiparva-part1.pdf calls some of these dhyana shlokas.

Comment: Yeah, some of them are Dhyana Shlokas, like verse 9.  By the way, verse 10 is from the Hayagriva Stotram, a hymn to Hayagriva composed by Vedanta Desikan, a Sri Vaishnava Acharya who lived in the 13th century.  So that indicates that this opening is of fairly recent origin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[mahabharata-resources.org](http://mahabharata-resources.org/) calls them benedictory verses and they are translated by Satya Chaitanya. These verses are not present in the critical edition of Mahabharata.

These verses in Sanskrit are taken from [here](http://mahabharata-resources.org/southern/benedict.pdf) and the English translation is from [here](http://mahabharata-resources.org/southern/MB_Benedictory_verses_translation.pdf) as below.

> *jayati parāśarasūnuḥ satyavatīhṛdayanandano vyāsaḥ* 
>   *yasyāsyakamalakośe vāṅmayam amṛtaṃ pibati lokaḥ* 
>   **1.** 
>   Victory to Vyasa, son of Parashara, delighter of the heart of
>   Satyavati, from the flower-cup of whose lotus face the world
>   drinks the nectar of words.
>
> *dharmadr.d.habaddhamūlo vedaskandhah. purān.aśākhād.hyah*
>   *kratukusumo moks.aphalo jayati kalpadrumo vis.n.uh*
>   **2.**
>   Victory to Vishnu, the wish-fulfilling tree, with dharma for its
>   strong, binding roots, the Vedas for its trunk, the puranas for its
>   branches, the sacrifices for its flowers, and salvation as its fruit.
>
> *pitāmahādyaṃ pravadanti ṣaṣṭhaṃ; maharṣim akṣayyavibhūtiyuktam*
>   *nārāyaṇasyāṃśajam ekaputraṃ; dvaipāyanaṃ vedanidhiṃ namāmi*
>   **3.**
>   I salute Dwaipayana [Vyasa], the treasure house of the Vedas, who
>   is said to be the sixth down from the Creator, the great sage
>   endowed with undecaying glories, the one-son born of a part of
>   Narayana.
>
> *pārāśaryavacassarojam amalaṃ gītārthagandhotkaṭaṃ*
>   *nānākhyānakakesaraṃ harikathāsaṃbodhanābodhitam*
>   *loke sajjanaṣaṭpadair aharahaḥ pepīyamānaṃ mudā*
>   *bhūyād bhāratapaṅkajaṃ kalimalapradhvaṃsi naḥ śreyase*
>   **4.**
>   May the pure lotus of the Mahabharata, born in the lake of the
>   words of Vyasa, intensely sweet with the fragrance of the meaning
>   of the Gita, with the several stories as its stamens, which has been
>   told to enlighten us about the story of the lord, the destroyer of the
>   dirt of the Kali age, drunk joyously by the bees of good men in the
>   world, bestow good on us.
>
> *yaḥ śvetatvam upāgataḥ kṛtayuge tretāyuge raktatāṃ*
>   *yugme yaḥ kapilaḥ kalau ca bhagavān kṛṣṇatvam āyāga*
>     *. . . . . . . danti munayo yo yogibhir gīyate*
>   *sa brahmā yadi vā haro yadi śivo yaḥ ko 'pi tasmai namaḥ*
>   **5.**
>   *[Incomplete verse. Not translated.]*

I didn't find any translation of the above verse. But my understanding of Sanskrit says that this verse is talking about the color of Lord in all yugas and oneness of the Trinity.

> *vāgīśādyāḥ sumanasaḥ sarvārthānām upakrame*
>   *yam˙ natvā kṛtakṛtyāḥ syus taṃ namāmi gajānanam*
>   **6.**
>   Salutations to the elephant-faced god bowing down to whom
>   cheerfully before all beginnings, the gods beginning Brahma, the
>   lord of the word, consider themselves blessed.
>
> *vyāsaṃ vasiṣṭhanaptāraṃ śakteḥ pautram akalmaṣam*
>   *parāśarātmajaṃ vande śukatātaṃ taponidhim*
>   **7.**
>   I salute that treasure-house of austerities, Vyasa, the great
>   grandson of Vasishtha, the sinless grandson of Shakti, the son of
>   Parashara.
>
> *acaturvadano brahmā dvibāhur aparo harih*
>   *abhālalocanaḥ śambhur bhagavān bādarāyaṇaḥ*
>   **8.**
>   Bhagavan Badarayana [Vyasa] is indeed Brahma minus his four
>   faces a second Vishnu with only two arms, and Shiva minus his
>   third eye.
>
> *śuklāmbaradharaṃ devaṃ śaśivarṇaṃ caturbhujam*
>   *prasannavadanaṃ dhyāyet sarvavighnopaśāntaye*
>   **9.**
>   Salute the Lord dressed in pure white clothes, the moon-hued one
>   with four hands and the cheerful face, for the cessation of all
>   obstacles.
>
> *jñānānandamayaṃ devaṃ nirmalaṃ sphaṭikākṛtim*
>   *ādhāraṃ sarvavidyānāṃ hayagrīvam upāsmahe*
>   **10.**
>   I worship Lord Hayagriva, whose nature is knowledge and bliss,
>   who is faultless and in the form of a crystal, and who is the basis
>   of all knowledge.
>
> *vyāsāya viṣṇurūpāya vyāsarūpāya viṣṇave*
>   *namo vai brahmanidhaye vāsiṣṭhāya namo namaḥ*
>   **11.**
>   Salutations to Vyasa who is none other than Vishnu! Salutations to
>   Vishnu in the form of Vyasa! Salutations to the treasure house of
>   spiritual wisdom! Salutations again and again to the sage born in
>   the line of Vasishtha!
>
> *namo dharmāya mahate namaḥ kṛṣṇāya vedhase*
>   *brāhmaṇebhyo namaskṛtvā dharmān vakṣyāmi śāśvatān*
>   **12.**
>   Salutations to the great Dharma! Salutations to the wise Krishna!
>   Having saluted the brahmanas, I shall now speak of the eternal
>   dharmas.
>
> *abhraśyāmaḥ piṅgajaṭābaddhakalāpaḥ*
>   *prāṃśur daṇḍī kṛṣṇamṛgatvakparidhānaḥ*
>   *sākṣāl lokān pāvayamānaḥ kavimukhyaḥ*
>   *pārāśaryaḥ parvasu rūpaṃ vivṛṇotu*
>   **13.**
>   Dark as the clouds, with terrible looking yellow hair and beard, of
>   short height, with a stick in his hand and wearing the skin of a
>   black antelope, the chief of poets who sanctifies all the worlds –
>   may that son of Parashara reveal his form in all the parvas.
>
> *aśubhāni nirācaṣṭe tanoti śubhasaṃtatim*
>   *smṛtamātreṇa yaḥ puṃsāṃ brahma tan maṅgalaṃ viduḥ*
>   **14.**
>   May that Brahman that destroys inauspiciousness and increases
>   auspiciousness in men by its mere remembrance bring good to us.
>
> *dharmo vivardhati yudhiṣṭhirakīrtanena*
>   *pāpaṃ praṇaśyati vṛkodarakīrtanena*
>   *śatrur vinaśyati dhanaṃjayakīrtanena*
>   *mādrīsutau kathayatāṃ na bhavanti rogāḥ*
>   **15.**
>   Dharma multiplies by the ritual repetition of Yudhishthira’s name.
>   Sin is destroyed by the repetition of Bheema’s name. And when
>   Arjuna’s name is remembered, enemies are destroyed. And no
>   disease will come to those who repeat the names of the sons of
>   Madri.
>
> *sarasvatīpadaṃ vande śriyaḥ patim umāpatim*
>   *tviṣāṃ patiṃ gaṇapatiṃ bṛhaspatimukhān ṛṣīn*
>   **16.**
>   I bow down before the feet of Saraswati, and before the husband
>   of Shree and of Uma. I bow down before Ganapati, the lord of
>   obstacles, and before all the sages beginning with Brihaspati.
>
> *nārāyaṇaṃ suraguruṃ jagadekanāthaṃ*
>   *bhaktapriyaṃ sakalalokanamaskṛtaṃ ca*
>   *traiguṇyavarjitam ajaṃ vibhum ādyam īśaṃ*
>   *vande bhavaghnam asurāsurasiddhavandyam*
>   **17.**
>   I bow down to Narayana, the greatest of the gods, the one master
>   of the universe, the lover of devotees, revered by the whole world;
>   who is beyond the three gunas, the unborn, the most glorious one,
>   the primal one, the lord of all. I bow down to the destroyer of
>   samsara, the one who is saluted by the devas, the asuras, the
>   siddhas, all.

Comment: I found the (supposed) full version of verse 5 

http://gretil.sub.uni-goettingen.de/gretil/1_sanskr/2_epic/mbh/mbh_13_u.htm 

13,001.000*0002_01 yaḥ śvetatvam upāgataḥ kṛtayuge tretāyuge raktatāṃ
13,001.000*0002_02 yugme yaḥ kapilaḥ kalau sa bhagavān kṛṣṇatvam abhyāgataḥ
13,001.000*0002_03 yaṃ vedāntavido vadanti munayo yo yogibhir gīyate
13,001.000*0002_04 sa brahmā yadi vā haro yadi hariḥ pāyāj jagad durgateḥ

I have no idea about the translation though.

Comment: @Arya good find